# Running number with multiple instance C# program

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2012

I would like to check with you all regarding running multi-instances of same program (in different PC) with a running number (non-duplicate) field on it.

*Program outline* 
- Program will get running number from DB (Eg: LoanID from LoanRef table) 
- User input info and click on Save. 
- Program will save the information to DB (eg: Loan table)

Currently, the program will retrieve the latest running number from DB (SQL Server 2012) and put it in read only text filed on the program.

During my development testing, I only tested with one program on one PC and it worked fine. 
When I tested with multiple PC, access (almost) at the same time, the running number become a problem.

Is there anyway to prevent such kind of running number issue (while allowing multiple instances of the same program).

I think of generate the number at the end of 'Save' process but the problem is user wants to see the number before save. So, I need to get it when form load occurs.

And I also can't disable multiple instances with Mutex because more than one person needs to use this program.

Any idea on what functions or features that I should use or check?

Comment: Try use "Transactions" in database to lock transaction and the number won't duplicate

Comment: You can create a new record in that table whenever you are opening the form to the user. Then when the user click save button you can update it(instead of inserting) with the number in the readonly text field.

Comment: @User2012384, I will read through this "Transactions" for DB. To be honest and lack of skill, this is my first time see this function.

Comment: @Olivarsham, thanks for your suggestion, I think I will go with your way. For my current situation, this one will be more easy to implements.
On my next version up, I will check with this "Transactions".